# How to check if SharePoint URL exists?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, csom

Let's say we have the following SharePoint working URL:

```
https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/Test.aspx
```

The following code works for determining if the URL works or not unless the user is authenticated with Azure AD access token

```
var request = NetHelper.CreateWebRequest(url,
                    allowAutoRedirect: true,
                    method: WebRequestMethods.Http.Head);
......
// Authentication
......
bool exists = false;
using (var response = request.GetResponseWithRetry())
{
    if (response != null)
    {
        exists = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK;
    }
}
```

This method works when we have the `CookieContainer` (username/password authentication) for authenticating. However, as per https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/248732/how-to-get-cookies-after-obtaining-azure-ad-access-token-to-sharepoint-online/248735 it's not possible to make `WebRequest` work when Azure AD authentication is being used and we apply `HttpRequestHeader.Authorization` header.

I tried to use CSOM library:

```
var csomFile = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
context.Load(csomFile, f => f.Exists);
context.ExecuteQueryWithRetry();
bool exists = csomFile != null && csomFile.Exists;
```

However, this kind of code works only for actual files (I guess). It always returns `False` for the URL `https://mywebsite.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/Test.aspx`.

So, my question is - Is there a way to determine if the URL exists using CSOM library, assuming we already have the authenticated `ClientContext` object (which can use either `CookieContainer` or `HttpRequestHeader.Authorization` header).

Comment: Why would you want to check if a page (or an url) exists using a JWT token? The pages are intended for user interaction, not for a programmatic access. I.e. what is your reason to test if the path exists?

Comment: @Nikolay, we are dealing with files which contain thousands of links in this format. Some of those links are working and some are broken (the page does not exist and SharePoint shows "Sorry, something went wrong" in the browser). We want to programmatically separate working links from broken ones.

Comment: You could try using the "CookieContainer" method **without AD Authorization** (i.e. with direct login/password, "simulating" user login), especially if it's your own organization. Could this be an option? You could have a dedicated app password for example for this purpose (to avoid 2FA). Or you absolutely need the Azure AD authentication?

Comment: @Nikolay, "CookieContainer" authorization works with a simple WebRequest as I wrote in the ticket description. However, we are supporting both login/password and AD authorizations and we let users to choose which one to use. So, at this moment, our URL checking code works only for login/password authentication and we are trying to make it work for AD authorization too. Unfortunately, keeping a method which works for only 1 type of authentication is not an option for us.

Comment: I see. Sorry, don't know how to do it with Azure AD. But good luck!

Comment: Does getting "lists of valid URL's" help you in your quest? (If it's not in the "list", it's not valid; at least from a "parent" point of view). https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23517/getting-the-urls-of-the-sharepoint-sites-lists-and-list-views-using-managed-cli#:~:text=For%20the%20SP.Site%20use%20the%20get_url%20%28%29%20%22property%22.,%28%29%3B%29.%20Then%20build%20the%20full%20url%20from%20there.

Comment: Don't think that's a solution, there can be tons of URLs.

Answer (score 3):

Sort of investigation why the scenario of using of Azure AD token is not possible to make "old-fashioned" calls (or, more precisely, explicitly disabled). As of my knowledge/findings, of course. I would be happy to be mistaking, but if not, then here's the situation.

The Microsoft's own applications (such Teams, Sharepoint Mobile, etc.) are using a special cookie to get web pages, and they get it using an undocumented method call, `_api/SP.OAuth.NativeClient/Authenticate`. When called with Azure AD token, this method returns a cookie that can be used for "classic" SharePoint web calls, the cookie returned is `SPOIDCTL`. Those clients are just including this cookie to the SharePoint "web" calls and can render views, for example, or get pages.

However, this functionality is only enabled for these specific Microsoft apps (detected by their "client IDs"). A third-party app will get 403 if it tries to call that API.

The motivation for this, as far as I understand, is that Microsoft is moving away from cookies auth, and it does not want to encourage third-party apps to use it or depend on it.

Here are some references:

- https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/7743
- https://www.devjhorst.com/2020/04/